# Adding values not including duplicates

Tags: r

I have the following data frame in R (actual data frame is millions of rows with thousands of unique Column A values):

```
Row  Column A   Column B 

1       130077     65         
2       130077     65         
3       130077     65         
4       200040     10         
5       200040     10
```

How can I add up Column B values grouped by Column A values without including duplicated Column A values? Correct output would be:

```
130077 65
200040 10
........
```

I have tried using filter and group_by with no success since the final output does sum values by Column A values but includes duplicated values.

Comment: You say you want to sum values of column B, but the output you show doesn't have those values summed. Which is it you're trying to get?

Answer (score 0):

An option is to get the `distinct` rows, then do a group by 'ColumnA' and get the `sum` of 'ColumnB'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
    distinct(ColumnA, ColumnB) %>% # The example gives the expected output here
    group_by(ColumnA) %>%
    summarise(ColumnB = sum(ColumnB))
```

---

Or in `base R` with `unique` and `aggregate`

```
aggregate(ColumnB ~ ColumnA, unique(df1[c("ColumnA", "ColumnB")]), sum)
```